# Update mysql cell after fetching related cell value via select?

Tags: mysql

SQL:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE results
SET result_value = '".$row[0]['logo_value']."'
WHERE logo_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['logo_id'])."'
AND user_id = '".$user_data[0]['user_id']."'");
```

This results table also contains result_tries I'd like to fetch before doing update, so I can use it to modify result_value... Is there a way to do it in a single shot instead of first doing select and than doing update?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
UPDATE results SET result_value = result_value + $row[0][logo_value]
```

for just a simple addition. You **CAN** use existing fields in the record being updated as part of the update, so if you don't want just addition, there's not too many limits on what logic you can use instead of just `x = x + y`.

Comment: I don't want same cell which I'm updating.
I need: UPDATE results SET result_value = $row[0][logo_value] -result_tries

Comment: so go for it. if that result_tries comes from the SAME record you're updating, that'llw ork. you can use ANY field in the record as part of the update. e.g. `set field1 = field2 + field3 * field4 / $value`.

Comment: That worked :) But what if I want to do some complicated math? Or for example check the outcome of the $row[0][logo_value] -result_tries and if it is 0 or less than 0, normalize result to 1?

Comment: you can also have `result = if(some weird condition, true result, false result)`. basically any arbitrary code that'll return a valid value for the field you're updating.